# How can I calculate Q, P, TP from AR=20-2Q?

Tags: industrial-organisation

Only data I have is Average Revenue: **AR=20-2Q**

How can I calculate **Q** - Quantity, **P** - Price and Total Profit - **TP**?

Thanks for help

Comment: This is not mathematical economics but homework, so please change the tagging. Also, what exactly is "Total Price"?

Comment: Sorry its Total Profit

Comment: This question does not meet the standards for homework question as spelled out in the relevant meta posts (see [here](http://meta.economics.stackexchange.com/questions/24/how-should-we-deal-with-homework-questions)).

Comment: Sorry, it was the fastest way to help my girlfriend for tomorrow's exam. Next time I will do my best :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how I would solve it :

Finding Q, P, and $\pi$

$AR = 20 - 2Q$

Know : $AR = \frac{R}{Q}$ and $R = PQ$

Therefore :

$R = 20Q - 2Q^2$

$PQ = 20Q - 2Q^2$

$\Rightarrow$ $ P = 20 - 2Q$ $\hspace{22mm} (1)$

$\Rightarrow$ $ Q = \frac{P - 20}{2}$ $\hspace{28mm} (2)$

$\Rightarrow$ $ \pi = 20Q - 2Q^2 - C$ $\hspace{8mm} (3)$

Additional Information :

$AC = 3Q$ and $MC = MR$

Know : $AC = \frac{C}{Q}$

Therefore :

$C = 3Q^2$

Max $\pi$

$ \pi = 20Q - 2Q^2 - 3Q^2$

$\frac{\partial \pi}{\partial Q} = 20 - 4Q - 6Q = 0$

Solve for Q then plug into (1) to find P:

$Q = 2$ and $P = 16$

Plug P and Q into $\pi$

$\pi = 20(2) - 2(2^2) - 3(2^2)$

$\pi = 20$

[image]

Comment: And in case there are extra conditions: **AC=3Q** and **MC=MR** I get results Q=2, P=16, TP=20. Dont ask me how I get it :D Are the results OK?

Comment: I think you're missing some other information.  Did you get those answers from a solutions manual?  Is this from a book?

Comment: Consider that the company maximizes profit. That is only extra information. Someone else calculated it. If you got some other results, let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Ok....it looks good then.  Please mark as answered :)

Comment: Sorry but how do they get it?

Comment: I've updated the answer....let me know if you have questions....i think I got all the equations formatted correctly